# add logging to a utility package

Tags: java, log4j, logging

I'm creating a java open source utility package and I would like to know if it is ok to include logging (like log4j) into that package.

The dilemma is if I include log4j into my package, where will i output the log file, I wouldn't want the log file to be at a wrong place for the user, but i would still want to create logs for debugging.

As well there is the issue of the user wanting to integrate my logs into the project itself.
and how will he be able to do that.

What would you recommend is the best way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the normal way to do it, is not include the Log4j Jar in the package and let the library user to decide which version of Log4j to use.

Also you don't have to worry about where to output the log file, since the user will have its own log4j.properties or log4j.xml configuration.

The library user can also decide which level of logging to use from your library or whether to suppress it. For instance with Amazon AWS libraries, I can tell that I only want warning messages or the output will be too verbose. In that case I add to my log4j.properties:

```
log4j.logger.com.amazonaws=WARN
```

Said that, I'd also remind you that a modern alternative to log4j is [SL4J](http://www.slf4j.org/).

Comment: so if i don't have the log4j included in the package how will i go about producing logs?

Comment: what I mean is of course you use your log4j JAR for development, but when you ship your JAR you don't include it, the user will include his own. Is it more clear?

Comment: yep. i just realized that the logger class is not a part of log4j, but actually a part of the java.util
one last question though, if the user does not include log4j into his application. what will happen when i write to the logger but there is no log4j to catch my logs if you understand what i mean.

Comment: and if nothing is found? will it just print the output to the console as default behavior?

Comment: well there is also org.apache.log4j.Logger -- java.util.logging.Logger is part of **Java Logging API**, which is a kind of wrapper that will try to use a logging framework depending on what is found in the classpath.

Comment: yes, the default handler is the [console handler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/ConsoleHandler.html) and so messages will be printed to the console.